# wordpress dashboard pop up add how to remove in chrome

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome

This image pop up open in my chrome.How to remove it.I have reinstall chrome but image pop is show.I have deleted cookie history adwclernear etc try it but i can't remove this image pop up.

[image]

Comment: Its an extension or some marvel effect

Comment: but how to remove

Comment: You have to scan using antivirus

Comment: this is not wordpress problem.its browser issue

Answer (score 0):

**Reason :**

- you might have unwanted software or malware installed on your computer:
- Pop-up ads won't go away.
- Your Chrome homepage or search engine keeps changing or is not set to Google - anymore.
- Unwanted Chrome extensions or toolbars keep coming back.
- You keep getting redirected to unfamiliar webpages.

**Solution**

- Remove unwanted programs from Chrome

  On your Windows computer, visit the Chrome Cleanup Tool website.https://www.google.com/chrome/cleanup-tool/
- Remove unwanted programs

  You can also try [MalwareBytes](https://www.malwarebytes.org/), an anti-malware program that can find other malicious software that the Chrome Cleanup Tool might not remove.
- Reset your browser settings
  On your computer, open Chrome.At the top right, click More More.Select Settings. At the bottom, click Show advanced settings. Under the "Reset settings" section, click Reset settings.Confirm by clicking Reset.

That's it.

Comment: i am check it in my control panel and i will used cleanup tool and i reinstall the chrome but add is display

Comment: did you share a control panle screen?? and browser extension screen shot??